# Implementing Socket IO in Flask

Tags: nginx, flask, socket.io, nginx-reverse-proxy, flask-socketio

Virtual Host

```
server {
server_name  ___;
root         /var/www/html/site_monitoring/public;

access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log;

index index.php;

# charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

if (!-d $request_filename) {
    rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~* \.php$ {
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
}   

location ~/\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pkc.hyd-ant.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pkc.hyd-ant.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

location /mysocket {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/socket.io;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}}
```

I'm encountering challenges while implementing Socket IO in Flask. Despite my efforts, I'm facing issues with the WebSocket functionality. Could anyone offer guidance or tips on how to effectively integrate Socket IO into Flask applications? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

I attempted Socket IO integration in Flask, expecting stable real-time communication but encountered persistent connection issues

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.